# como hacer un punto de silla de matrices en c

Tags: c, matrices, matemáticas

Estoy haciendo un programa de matrices y necesito buscar el punto de silla de matrices, dadas previamente por el usuario.

Aquí están todas las variables que utilicé, tengo que pedir al usuario que digite los datos de las matrices, y después está el menú que te da la opción de realizar diferentes cosas. Me falta la de punto de silla.

```
int main()
    {
             int B[2][2],A[2][2],i=0,j=0,opc=0;
            
             printf("Matriz uno datos\n");
             for (i=0;i<2;i++)
             {
             for(j=0;j<2;j++)
             {
             printf("\nIngrese %d,%d:",i+1,j+1);
             scanf("%d",&A[i][j]);
             }
             }
             printf("\nMatriz dos datos:\n");
             for (i=0;i<2;i++)
             {
             for(j=0;j<2;j++)
             {
             printf("\nIngrese %d,%d:",i+1,j+1);
             scanf("%d",&B[i][j]);
             }
             }
            system("cls");
            printf("1-SUMAR\n");
            printf("2-MULTIPLICAR\n");
            printf("3-RESTA\n");
            printf("4-PUNTO DE SILLA\n");
            printf("5-SALIR\n");
            printf("ELIJA UNA OPCION: \n");
            scanf("%d",&opc);
```

Si alguien me ayuda a hacer los puntos de silla se lo agradecería.